# how to copy and send server response containing null--proxy implementation

Tags: c, proxy

I am trying to implement proxy.

I can receive resposne from server, but having problems sending response to client.

For the first response I received, it contains header and part of message body
I need to modify header, therefore I had to seperate header and message body.
For rest packets, I believe there is no header to be modified, so just send them directly.

```
    //receive response from server
    char res_buf[1024];
    char* res_buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(res_buf));
    char* res_line = (char*)malloc(sizeof(res_buf));
    int packet=0;
    while(1){
        char response[1024];
        int n = recv(connfd_to_server, res_buf, 1024,0);
        strcpy(res_buffer, res_buf);
        if (n <=0){
            printf("will break");
            break;
        }
        else{
            if(packet == 0){  //header modification
                res_line = strtok(res_buf, "\r\n");
                for(int i = 0; i<=12; i++){
                    if(i==10){  //add this in the 11th line
                        strcat(response, "Via:1.1\r\n");
                    }
                    else{
                        strcat(response, res_line);
                        strcat(response, "\r\n");//everyline ends with'\r\n'
                    }
                    res_line = strtok(NULL, "\r\n");
                }
                //printf("response header is:\n%s\n", response);

                //Here problem comes!
                **//Here I try to copy messageBody to response, but failed**
                char* messageBody = (char*)malloc(1024);
                char* mess_temp = (char*)malloc(1024);
                mess_temp = strtok(res_buffer,"\r\n");
                for(int j = 0; j<=11; j++){
                    mess_temp = strtok(NULL,"\r\n");
                    //here, ignore header content(first 12lines)
                }
                mess_temp = strtok(NULL,"");
                printf("mess_temp last is%s\n", mess_temp);
                memcpy(messageBody, mess_temp,1024);//copy messageBody
                strcat(response, messageBody);
                printf("response is:\n%s\n", response);
                send(connfd_to_client, response, 1024, 0);
                packet++;** 
            }
            else{//there is no header to be modified in rest packet,just send 
                send(connfd_to_client, res_buf, n, 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am using memcpy() to copy message body byte by byte, considering there can be NULL in message body.

Here is the result

[image]

**And webpage says"content encoding error".
Seem like memcoy() didn't copy message body successfully?**
I am not sure what to try now. Could you help me

Many thanks in advance

Comment: If a function's name includes `str`, then it is expecting a string as an argument. Strings cannot contain NULs, because the first NUL terminates the string. This applies not just to strcpy; also to strtok, strlen, etc, etc

Comment: @rici So, after I memcpy() message body, I guess I should not strcat() it to response right? Then should I send header and message separately?  How can I send modified header and message body together to client?

Comment: You don't have to send them together, and there is no guarantee that you will receive them together. That's not how TCP works; it's just a stream of data without any implicit division into packets.

Comment: @rici I mean there are many trunks of data my proxy receives from server. For the first trunk, it contains header and part of message body. For the rest trunk, I just send them directly. I am only taking about first trunk. I want to modify header, and then combina header and message body, send them to client. However, I think I failed to combine modified header and message body successfully.

Comment: I understood that and my comment stands. There is no need to send the header and message data as a single chunk. You don't even need to send the header as a single chunk. So all that copying is unnecessary.

Comment: @rici I copied it because I need to modify one line in header.

Comment: But you don' t have to copy because you can send the first part, then send your change, then send the rest.

Comment: @rici  I see!!! THX!!